# Node SSH2 double ssh connection

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am trying to make 2 jumps via ssh with node with the ultimate goal of connecting to a database. The idea is:

`local ->ssh-> bastion1 ->ssh-> bastion2`

I can't quite figure this out, i keep getting an error on the second ssh saying `error ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.xxx:22`.

My current code looks like this:

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;

doubleBastion (sshConfig, dbConfig, debug = false) {
      dbConfig = this.addDefaults(dbConfig);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connOne = new Client();
        connOne.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('SSH 1 CONNECTED!');
            connTwo = new Client();
            connTwo.on('ready', () => {
                console.log('SSH 2 CONNECTED!');
                // establish db connection
            
            }).connect({
                passphrase: 'thepassword',
                host: 'x.x.x.x',
                user: 'ubuntu',
                privateKey: sshConfig.key
            });
        }).connect(sshConfig);
      });
 }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Is this possible? Sure... This question will need more to be useful

Comment: What is `Client`? A library? What kind?

Comment: @Dominik I'd assume it was this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2

Comment: Yeah good call. Looks like it

Comment: You're still trying to connect to _bastion2_ from your local machine. What you're after is a [multi-hop tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Comment: There's already an example of connection hopping right in the `ssh2` readme.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the double jump using ssh2 in Node

Define ssh credentials for tunnel and destination server

```
const tunnelSSH = {
    host: '192.168.70.169',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
}


const destinationSSH = {
   host:'192.168.70.170',
   port:22,
   username: 'username',
   password: 'password'
}


const portforwardConfig = {
   srcHost: '127.0.0.1', // source host
   srcPort: 22, // source port
   dstHost: destinationSSH.host, // destination host
   dstPort: destinationSSH.port // destination port
 };
```

Define common function to do the ssh and execute the command in destination server

```
const sshHoping = function(forwardConfig, tunnelSSH, destinationSSH, command) { return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{

const ssh1 = new Client();
const ssh2 = new Client();
ssh1.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('FIRST :: connection ready');
    // Alternatively, you could use something like netcat or socat with exec()
    // instead of forwardOut(), depending on what the server allows
    ssh1.forwardOut(forwardConfig.srcHost, forwardConfig.srcPort, forwardConfig.dstHost, forwardConfig.dstPort, (err, stream) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('FIRST :: forwardOut error: ' + err);
            ssh1.end();
            reject('FIRST :: forwardOut error: ' + err)
        }
        ssh2.connect({
            sock: stream,
            username: destinationSSH.username,
            password: destinationSSH.password,
        });
    });
}).connect(tunnelSSH);

ssh2.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('SECOND :: connection ready');
    ssh2.exec(command, (err, stream) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('SECOND :: exec error: ' + err);
            ssh1.end();
            reject('SECOND :: exec error: ' + err)
        }
        stream.on('close', () => {
            ssh1.end(); // close parent (and this) connection
        }).on('data', (data) => {
            ssh1.end();
            resolve(data.toString())
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
    });
});

 })}
```

Main function to make a call

```
const doubleBastion = async(data) => {

    const command = "free -m"
    await sshHoping(portforwardConfig,tunnelSSH,destinationSSH, command).then(function(result){
      console.log(result)
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log("Error : "+e.message)
      });
  }
```